# void pointer typecasting

Tags: c, void-pointers

I was trying to understand void pointer typecasting in C. I wrote a program to try and create a segmentation fault, but I am not getting it. Can someone please explain to me why

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long U32; 
int main()
{
  void *obj;
  U32 value = 25;
  U32* ptr;
  printf("*(ptr)                           : %lu\n", *(ptr));
  obj = &value;
  ptr = &value;
  ptr++;  
  printf("*(U32 *)(obj)                    : %lu\n", *(U32 *)(obj)); 
  printf("*((U32 *)(obj) + 1)              : %lu\n", *((U32 *)(obj) + 1));   
  printf("*(U32 *)((U32 *)(obj) + 1)       : %lu\n", *(U32 *)((U32 *)(obj) + 1)); 
  printf("*(ptr)                           : %lu\n", *(ptr));
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
*(ptr)                           : 458998657
*(U32 *)(obj)                    : 25
*((U32 *)(obj) + 1)              : 3215085752
*(U32 *)((U32 *)(obj) + 1)       : 3215085752
*(ptr)                           : 3215085752
```

The way I see it only the 2nd printf is legal as all others are referring to some uninitialized random memory and should cause a seg fault

Comment: You mostly get segfaults when you access memory that is protected. Memory you are accessing may or may not be protected (probably not since usually variables are allocated sequentially, but they do not have to be at all).

Comment: You are unlucky that the first `printf()` doesn't crash; your `ptr` must happen to contain a sufficiently pointer valid value to not crash, although it is formally undefined behaviour (and undefined behaviour includes 'appearing to work').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 U32* ptr;
  printf("*(ptr)                           : %lu\n", *(ptr));
```

`ptr` is uninitialized so it is undefined behavior to dereference it,

```
  obj = &value;
  ptr = &value;
  ptr++;  
  printf("*(U32 *)(obj)                    : %lu\n", *(U32 *)(obj));
```

Ok, as long as `obj` is pointing to a valid U32 (and U32 has to be an unsigned long as you're using %lu as the printf format)

```
  printf("*((U32 *)(obj) + 1)              : %lu\n", *((U32 *)(obj) + 1));
```

You're trying to dereference a pointer that points one U32 past any valid location, so it's undefined behavior.

```
  printf("*(U32 *)((U32 *)(obj) + 1)       : %lu\n", *(U32 *)((U32 *)(obj) + 1));
```

Same as above.

```
  printf("*(ptr)                           : %lu\n", *(ptr));
```

Since you incremented `ptr` , it points one U32 past anything valid, which leads to undefined behavior.

As your code does things that invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), it's really hard and often impossible to reason about what is going to happen. It's undefined. Something unexpected could happen. Something bad could happen. Nothing bad could happen, and so on. Doing something in C that you should not do, does not mean it will segfault.

Answer (score 2):

UB is funny like that- the behaviour is undefined, not guaranteed segfault. The address of `obj + 1` is probably some other spot on the stack which is allocated to your program anyway. To get an *almost* guaranteed segfault, just de-reference `obj` before it has ever been assigned.

Comment: @skynorth: No he doesn't. He says `obj = &value;` first.

Comment: Oh I was talking about U32* ptr and he prints it immediately.

Comment: "To get a guaranteed segfault, just de-reference obj before it has ever been assigned." The essence of UB is that there behaviour cannot be guaranteed. Even if `obj` is never assigned, de-referencing it is not guaranteed to result in seg fault.

Comment: @David: Indeed. I just edited to reflect that. However, it's realistically guaranteed on most implementations that de-referencing random pointers gives a hard error.

Comment: The OP has an example where it is not. The chances a random pointer points to something valid is rather large on a 32 bit processor utilizing a lot of memory, and might be a lot less on a 64 bit machine where not a lot of memory is mapped.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` points to a valid object (`value`) but `ptr++` does not point to an object. So accessing the element `*ptr` after the pointer increment is undefined behavior. `printf` of `*ptr` can display random data but can also crash your program.